# Exporting Database from SSMS to .mdf file and connect on vb.net application

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssms

I need to export my database from SSMS and connect in my VB application.

I have this connection string

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=\GestãoProjetos.mdf;Database=GestãoProjetos;Trusted_Connection=Yes
```

But how do I export my database to a `.mdf` file so I can use it on other computers?

Comment: You don't export databases when using a DB server, you install the DBs on them and connect to the servers. Or install the DBs on shared servers and all computers connect to the same instances.

Comment: yes but in my case i can't do that

Comment: Then you should not use SQL Server to begin with. It's inherently a database server, with all the administration overhead that implies. Look at SQLite for a simple portable database instead.

Comment: You might try using [SQL Sever Express LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the file from the database file location which was set during creating the database. To know the mdf file location, right click on your database in `SSMS` and click `Properties` and select `Files` from the left panel just like below :

[image]

Comment: yes, i did that, i copy the .mdf and the log files, copy them to another directory and in my vb application it gives me an error saying that the database already exists

Comment: if i understand, you already have the database in the server, that's why you are getting that error.

Comment: i suggest, use this connection string `Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=GestãoProjetos;Trusted_Connection=Yes`
then you can just take the database backup and restore to other location when needed.

Comment: ok, i did that, i deleted the one on the sql folder in (c:) and it gives me an error saying that the database can't be open

Comment: that is different issue. please make sure your database is accessible from SSMS.

Comment: yea, i can access it, now i removed the new .mdf file and it worked on vb, but i need it to work on another directory

Comment: detach your database from SSMS, move the database files to your desired folder, then attach it again.

Comment: ok it worked, so when i export the vb application i can access the database on other computer ? btw the file that i copy are in the folder that will contain the application exported